# ¿Cómo obtener la posición actual en un juego de árbol binario en C ++?

Tags: c++

Quiero crear un juego que busque en un árbol binario la hoja con el puntaje más alto. Por ejemeplo :

```
                   10
                 /    \
                6      14
               / \    /  \
              5   8  11  18
```

**Mi problema esta que tengo una clase para los arboles binarios, BTree, pero no sabe como construir una clase Board del juego con la posición actual.**

Así quiero crear una clase de `Board` que presenta un estado del juego en un momento dado. Mi problema es la creación del constructador `Board(btree)`. Porque no puedo encontrar la manera de conocer la posición actual en el juego

¿Qué es un Board? En mi opinión, en cualquier caso está hecho de un árbol binario. Pero necesitemos la posición actual tambien. Aquí está el prototipo y la clase de Board sin la posición  :

## Board

### Board.cpp

```
#include "Board.h"

Board::Board(){
    newLength = 0;
    newScore = 0;

}; 

Board::~Board(){

}; 

Board::Board(btree b){
    newLength = NULL; //TO-DO : cantidad de nodos que tienen hojas PERO ¿cómo contarlos?

    newScore = NULL; //TO-DO : número en el nodo actual PERO no sabemos de b que es el árbol actual.

    moves = NULL;//TO-DO matriz de las posiciones izquierda y derecha de la corrientestate  //node *left; and node *right;

}; 

// da la cantidad de hojas que podemos jugar: ya sea 2 o 0 en el caso del árbol binario.
int board::legalMoves(moves) 
{

    return NULL;

};
```

### Board.h

```
#include <iostream> //usefull ?
#include <string> //usefull ?
#include <vector>

#ifndef DEF_BOARD
#define DEF_BOARD

class Board{

    public:
        board();
        ~board();

        //un Board está hecha de un árbol binario. Además, tiene una un score, una longitud
        board(btree);

        //Y tiene posibles possibilidas
        legalMoves(moves)

    private:
        //member variables
        int length;
        int score;
        // crear move? Matriz de las siguientes posibilidades: izquierda / derecha? O ninguno si estamos al final
        vector<int> tableau(2,NULL);        

};

#endif
```

A mi paracer deberíamos hacer la siguiente función: hacer `Board(btree, node)` para resolver el problema con `node` quien estaría donde estamos.

Pienso que todo lo que sigue son solo recursos para comprender mejor el problema. Muestra la estructura de mi BTree y nodos. Todo el codigo, que no funciona por lo momento, esta sobre [GitHub](https://github.com/antoinecomp/NestedMonteCarloForBinaryTrees).

---

## Main con Btree y Node

```
#define NULL 0
#include "nestedSimple.c"
#include "Board.h"

// main2

struct node
{
  int key_value;
  node *left;
  node *right;
};

class btree
{
    public:
        btree();
        ~btree();

        void insert(int key);
        node *search(int key);
        void destroy_tree();

    private:
        void destroy_tree(node *leaf);
        void insert(int key, node *leaf);
        node *search(int key, node *leaf);

        node *root;
};

btree::btree()
{
  root=NULL;
}

btree::~btree()
{
  destroy_tree();
}

void btree::destroy_tree(node *leaf)
{
  if(leaf!=NULL)
  {
    destroy_tree(leaf->left);
    destroy_tree(leaf->right);
    delete leaf;
  }
}

void btree::insert(int key, node *leaf)
{
  if(key< leaf->key_value)
  {
    if(leaf->left!=NULL)
     insert(key, leaf->left);
    else
    {
      leaf->left=new node;
      leaf->left->key_value=key;
      leaf->left->left=NULL;    //Sets the left child of the child node to null
      leaf->left->right=NULL;   //Sets the right child of the child node to null
    }  
  }
  else if(key>=leaf->key_value)
  {
    if(leaf->right!=NULL)
      insert(key, leaf->right);
    else
    {
      leaf->right=new node;
      leaf->right->key_value=key;
      leaf->right->left=NULL;  //Sets the left child of the child node to null
      leaf->right->right=NULL; //Sets the right child of the child node to null
    }
  }
}
void btree::insert(int key)
{
  if(root!=NULL)
    insert(key, root);
  else
  {
    root=new node;
    root->key_value=key;
    root->left=NULL;
    root->right=NULL;
  }
}
node *btree::search(int key, node *leaf)
{
  if(leaf!=NULL)
  {
    if(key==leaf->key_value)
      return leaf;
    if(key<leaf->key_value)
      return search(key, leaf->left);
    else
      return search(key, leaf->right);
  }
  else return NULL;
}

node *btree::search(int key)
{
  return search(key, root);
}

void btree::destroy_tree()
{
  destroy_tree(root);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv []) {
    btree b;
    b.insert(5);
    b.insert(6);
    b.insert(8);
    b.insert(10);
    b.insert(11);
    b.insert(14);
    b.insert(18);

    // create board with b 
    board boa(b);

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Lo normal en un árbol binario es que la puntuación más alta sea la del nodo que esté más a la derecha, luego no termino de ver qué sentido tiene la pregunta... me da la sensación de que falta algo... alguna idea que tienes en tu mente y no has sabido plasmar en la pregunta

Comment: @eferion, Aquí depende, puede ser completamente aleatorio... Mi problema esta que tengo una clase para los arboles binarios, BTree, pero no sabe como construir una clase Board del juego con la posición actual. (Y también que soy un quiche en C ++)

Answer (score 0):

Quizás debieras modificar `Board` para que almacene un puntero de tipo `node`:

```
class btree
{
public:
  node* Root() const
  { return root; }
};

class Board{

  node* currentNode;

public:

  Board(btree tree)
    : currentNode{tree.Root()}
  { }
};
```

Si `Board` dispone de un puntero al nodo actual (entiendo que debería empezar por `root`), puede moverse por el arbol sin problemas.

También puedes disponer de un constructor que acepte el nodo directamente:

```
Board::Board(node* node)
  : currentNode{node}
{ }
```

En cualquier caso, crear un objeto de tipo `Board` es trivial.